# The maximal convex subset of non-convex region.

Tags: geometry, convex-analysis

Assume $\mathcal{X}$ is a closed non-convex set (take $\mathcal{X} \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ as an example). Then for each point $x_0 \in \mathcal{X}$, apparently there exists at least one **convex** region $C \subset \mathcal{X}$, that $x_0 \in C$.

My question is that, it there any method to find a $C^*$, which is the largest one in all possible $C$'s, i.e.
$$
\begin{split}
C^* = \arg & \max_C \iint_{(s,t)\in C} \mathrm{d}s \mathrm{d}t \\
\text{s.t.} \quad & C ~ \text{is convex} \\
& x_0 \in C \\
& C \subset \mathcal{X}
\end{split}
$$

And this maximum size $\iint_{(s, t) \in C^*} \mathrm{d}a \mathrm{d}b$ is a function of $x_0$, say $f(x_0)$. So how can I get this $f(x)$ for $\forall x \in \mathcal{X}$?

Comment: If you have a proof that there is a convex $C$ where this maximal value is attained, I'd like to see it. But I don't think you have one, or that it's true in general. If your $\mathcal{X}$ is bounded, the least upper limit will be finite, though.

Comment: Do you want to have $C \subset \mathcal X$?

Comment: @gerw edited, sorry for the ambiguity